# flex 4.6 datagrid column insert datas from another

Tags: php, apache-flex

At first I'would like to pleased for ignoring my language skills.
I'm creating an online app in flex with sdk 4.6.0 (flex+php)

What I'm trying to do is change 1 datagrid column datas from another (or the same if it will be more simple).

My data grid looks like:

```
id | name | type | type1 | type2 | type3 | ... | type52
```

data provider in this grid is a db table, than result is taking as new arrayCollection.
I would like to create this new arrayCollection with needed typeX column datas in type column. Each type have the same quantity of rows.
selecting of typeX is going by button pressing which is not situated in datagrid.
column visible function is not the solution because in the other parts of app I'm using `dataFiled="type" as text{function}` etc.

Let me know if some additional info will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectProxy class. For example:

```
package {

import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

import mx.utils.ObjectProxy;

public class Wrapper extends ObjectProxy {

    public function Wrapper(item:Object = null) {
        super(item);
    }

    override flash_proxy function getProperty(name:*):* {
        if (name == "type1")
            return "someValue";

        if (name == "type2")
            return "otherValue";

        return super.flash_proxy::getProperty(name);
    }
}
}
```

And when you create your ArrayCollection use this function:

```
public function wrapCollection(arrayCollection:IList):IList {
    var list:Array = [];
    for each (var item:Object in arrayCollection) {
        list.push(new Wrapper(item));
    }
    return new ArrayCollection(list);
}
```

Now you can use dataFields `type1` and `type2`